# Using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem to open a TcpClient connection and read data in ASP.NET and SignalR

Tags: c#, asp.net, threadpool, tcpclient, signalr

I've read a couple of posts on SignalR and thought for a fun test project that I could create a web application to poll my onkyo receiver for status and display the results in a browser.  For an initial test, I was successfully able to send the current time on the server back to the client by using this code in Application_Start:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{               
    dynamic clients = Hub.GetClients<KudzuHub>();
    while (true)
    {                
        clients.addMessage(DateTime.Now.ToString());

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
});
```

In the client javascript, i have the following code:

```
// Proxy created on the fly
var kHub = $.connection.kudzuHub;

// Declare a function on the hub so that the server can invoke it
kHub.addMessage = function (message) {
    console.log('message added');
    $('#messages').append('<li>' + message + '</li>');
};

// start the connection
$.connection.hub.start();
```

So all of that works fine.  Every second, I get a new list item containing the current server date and time.

Now when I add this code to read data from the Onkyo receiver, it breaks: (still in Application_Start)

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{  
    dynamic clients = Hub.GetClients<KudzuHub>();
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["receiverIP"].ToString();
            int port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["receiverPort"]);

            TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);

            NetworkStream clientSockStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
            clientSockStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);

            tcpClient.Close();

            clients.addMessage(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        // do something to handle the error
    }

});
```

I set a break point and stepped through the code.  It gets to this line and then returns.

```
clientSockStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
```

It never finishes the rest of the code to send the message to the client.  What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make some structural changes to your loop to allow the receiver time to respond, remove the overhead of retrieving the configuration every 50 milliseconds, and cleanup the open network stream:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ =>
{  
    dynamic clients = Hub.GetClients<KudzuHub>();
    TcpClient tcpClient = null;
    NetworkStream clientSockStream = null;

    try
    {
        string host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["receiverIP"].ToString();
        int port = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["receiverPort"]);

        while (true)
        {
            if (tcpClient == null) {
              tcpClient = new TcpClient(host, port);
              clientSockStream = tcpClient.GetStream();
            }

            if (clientSockStream.CanRead) {
                byte[] bytes = new byte[tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize];
                try {
                   clientSockStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                  // Add some debug code here to examine the exception that is thrown
                }

                tcpClient.Close();
                // Closing the client does not automatically close the stream
                clientSockStream.Close();

                tcpClient = null;
                clientSockStream = null;

                clients.addMessage(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes));
            }
            Thread.Sleep(50);
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException ex)
    {
        // do something to handle the error
    } finally {
       if (tcpClient != null) {
         tcpClient.Close();
         clientSockStream.Close();
       }
    } 

});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I implemented these changes but I got the same result.

Comment: @jmac: You should try adding an exception handler to the code to see what exception it is throwing. I will modify the answer to show where.

Comment: There was no exception.  I stepped through the code.  After the "clientSockStream.Read(...", it just returns to the browser.

Comment: @jmac: that is very bizarre; did you add some code to the exception handler and put a break point on that code? If there isn't an exception, then the only other thing I can think of is that it's a clr exception. You might want to check your windows event logs (application and system) for errors from iis (should be something about losing communication with an app pool or something similar).

Comment: Well I'm not sure what happened but today it is working fine.  Maybe a connection was left open on the receiver.  I've had it off for a few days.  I don't really know.  I appreciate your help @competent_tech.